# Visual Code css intellisense weird interaction

Tags: css, reactjs, visual-studio-code, intellisense

On a ReactJS project, if I choose the style Jsx Attribute for inline CSS,

[image: vs code suggested style attribute].

Then CSS intellisense won't work or work only after I add some fields manually.

But if I type the style attribute manually without clicking on the jsx attribute that VSCODE suggested, it would work normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes VSCode Intellisense does not work. not sure but this may be a bug but it shouldn't be that problematic.

but if it does bother you that much then try this [kite](https://www.kite.com/). kite is more like
auto-complete.

https://www.kite.com/integrations/vs-code/

And if don't want auto-complete then add [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ecmel.vscode-html-css) extension in your VSCode.
[image]